# Sticky menu duplication bug

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue with a website I'm building on any page other than the homepage. See: http://dev.webfold.co.uk/dn/blog/ - I have a sticky menu in place but if you scroll quickly down then back up with the mosuewheel (not the scrollbar) the menu duplicates in a really weird way. I've looked through all my code and can't understand why this is happening, it's really annoying. Would really appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Screenshot: [image: screenshot]

Comment: if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
     $('nav').addClass('sticky');
 } else {  
     $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
 }  
 };

Comment: I don't understand, this is just part of the code I'm already using.

Comment: yes there is the problem, sticky class not removing

Comment: Sticky class is removing fine...that's not the problem.